# How do I use regular expression to select from an array?

Tags: ruby

I have a code that asks for the user to either type Cats or Dogs then it'll search an array for everything that contains the word Cats or Dogs then puts them all out.

```
print "Cats or Dogs? "
userinput = gets.chomp

lines = [["Cats are smarter than dogs"],["Dogs also like meat"], ["Cats are nice"]]

lines.each do |line|
  if line =~ /(.*?)#{userinput}(.*)/
    puts line
  end
end
```

So If I were to input Cats. I should get two sentences:

```
Cats are smarter than dogs
Cats are nice
```

You could even input smarter and I'll get

```
Cats are smarter than dogs
```

I'm strictly looking for ways to use an regular expression to search through an array or string and take out the lines/sentences that match the expression.

If anyone is wondering, the lines array was originally from an file and I turned each line into an array part.

---

EDIT:

Wow, how far I came in the coding world.

```
print "Cats or Dogs? "
userinput = gets.chomp

lines = [["Cats are smarter than dogs"],["Dogs also like meat"], ["Cats are nice"]]

lines.each do |linesInside|
  linesInside.each do |line|
    if line =~ /(.*?)#{userinput}(.*)/
      puts line
    end
  end
end
```

Took literally 5 seconds to solve what took me ages to give up on at the time.

Comment: Case-sensitive? Does "Cats" match "The cat came back"? How about "Fries without catsup is like something else I can't think of right now"? Why do you have an array of arrays, each containing a single string, rather than just an array of strings?

Comment: I ran some benchmarks on @akuhn's and @Cary's algorithms: while  @Cary's runs faster on very short strings, it can become several orders of magnitude slower than @akuhn's the longer the strings in `lines` get. If performance is an issue you should keep this in mind.

Comment: @cobalsoda, what string sizes did you benchmark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
...
lines = ["Cats are smarter than dogs", "Dogs also like meat", "Cats are nice"]
regexp = Regexp.new(userinput)
selected_lines = lines.grep(regexp)
puts selected_lines
```

How does this work?

- `grep` filters an array using pattern matching
- Notice that I am using an array of strings. Your example code uses an array of single-element arrays, I assume you mean to just use an array of strings.

Comment: I notice that your array doesn't have [] around them which mine does due to splitting. Seems like I can't figure out how to use regular expressions properly when it does that but I think I can just remove the split.

Comment: I think you need to tweak your regex so that `"cats"` will match `"Cats"` but not `"catsup"`.

Comment: You're right. I did not focus on the internals  of the regexp itself though since the question seems to be focused on how to filter an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can, of course, do that without a regex.

```
lines = ["Dogs are smarter than cats", "Cats also like meat", "Dogs are nice"]

print "Cats or Dogs? "
input = gets.chomp.downcase
```

If `input #=> "dogs"`,

```
lines.select { |line| line.downcase.split.include?(input) }
  #=> ["Dogs are smarter than cats", "Dogs are nice"]
```

If `input #=> "cats"`,

```
lines.select { |line| line.downcase.split.include?(input) }
  #=> ["Dogs are smarter than cats", "Cats also like meat"]
```

Comment: The `split` is both unnecessary and progressively more inefficient the longer each string in `lines` is; I suggest removing it.

Comment: Also unnecessary: rewording `lines` to suggest dogs are better than cats,  which is objectively false ;)

Comment: I `split` on whitespace so that `"Cats"` wouldn't match `"catsup"`. I'm not really advocating this; I'd use the regex `/\b#{input}\b/i`.

Comment: `lines.group_by { |l| (l.downcase.split & %w[ cats dogs ])[0] }` is another way here.

Answer (score 0):

Since your array is an array of arrays, you could call [flatten](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) first :

```
lines.flatten.grep(/#{userinput}/i)
```

`i` is for case insensitive search, so that 'Dogs' matches 'Dogs' and 'dogs'.

If you want whole-word search :

```
lines.flatten.grep(/\b#{userinput}\b/i)
```

Finally, if you don't really need an array of arrays, just read an array from your file directly, either with `File.readlines(f)` or `File.foreach(f)`.